# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression! ImapX, Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, imap, imapx

I am trying to check the latest email of my Gmail inbox using IMAP. But for any reason here I am facing a library issue. Whatever library version I use the same issue comes. I am trying this code for any reason it's showing the following errors:

GAC    Version        Location

---

False  v2.0.50727     C:\Users\bijoy.rc\Downloads\ImapX.2.0.0.18\lib\net35\ImapX.dll
False  v2.0.50727     C:\Users\bijoy.rc\Downloads\LinqBridge.1.3.0\lib\net20\LinqBridge.dll
True
IMAP connection established
Client object is not null
False
Logged in to IMAP server as user: rayhan66.pg@gmail.com
An error occurred during login: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

**Code:**

```
try {
    ### Import the dll
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\bijoy.rc\Downloads\ImapX.2.0.0.18\lib\net35\ImapX.dll")
    ### Import the LinqBridge.dll
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\bijoy.rc\Downloads\LinqBridge.1.3.0\lib\net20\LinqBridge.dll")
    ### Create a client object
    $client = New-Object ImapX.ImapClient
    ### Set the fetching mode to retrieve the part of the message you want to retrieve,
    ### the less the better
    $client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = "Full"
    $client.Host = "imap.gmail.com"
    $client.Port = 993
    $client.UseSsl = $true

    try {
        $client.Connect()
        Write-Host "IMAP connection established"

        # Debug output to check the state of the $client object
        if ($client -ne $null) {
            Write-Host "Client object is not null"
            $user = "example@gmail.com"
            $password = "password"
            
            try {
                $client.Login($user, $password)
                Write-Host "Logged in to IMAP server as user: $user"
                
                $inbox = $client.Folders.Inbox
                $messages = $inbox.Search("ALL", $client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode, 1)
                
                if ($messages.Count -gt 0) {
                    $latestMessage = $messages[0]
                    $subject = $latestMessage.Subject
                    Write-Host "Latest email subject: $subject"
                } else {
                    Write-Host "No emails found in inbox."
                }
            } catch {
                Write-Host "An error occurred during login: $_"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "Client object is null"
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "An error occurred during connection: $_"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
}
```

I tried to just connect to my mail server and retrieve my latest email subject using powershell.

Comment: Is IMAP turned on? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=